# Custom python launcher for ipython jupyter

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I use a shell script (call it run_py.sh) to launch python. Is there a way to have the notebook run using this shell script instead of the normal python executable?

Comment: If you install a kernelspec (`python -m ipykernel install --user`), then there will be a JSON file containing the command to launch the kernel. Find it using `jupyter kernelspec list`, and then you can edit the command in there to run whatever you want.

Comment: Tried that already (changing the argv). When I ran the kernel, it didn't respond. :/

Comment: Seems like it could be a timeout issue. I would have to try increasing the timeout

Comment: Your script still has to end by starting a kernel with the correct connection file. What are you trying to do in this script?

Comment: I see. It seems like a simple replacement is not sufficient. I left the connection file as default. My log indicated that there is no module named "ipykernel". Seems like the kernel points to a different version of python than what my system has been using by default.

Comment: The kernelspec ipykernel creates hardcodes the path to the Python in use to create it. You'd probably want to use that same absolute path to Python in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Juypter kernel as suggested by @thomas-k as follow

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name kernelname --display-name "Python 3 (Kernel Name)"
```

then go to `C:\Users\Full Name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\kernelname` (in Windows), edit `kernel.json`, and point first entry of `argv` to your python executable.